# Making a custom function apply rowise in dplyr mutate

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a custom boolean function which checks a string (my actual function does more than that provided below, which is just provided as an illustrative example).

If I use the first version with dplyr::mutate() it just applies to the first value and then sets all rows to be that answer.

I can wrap the function in a purr::map() however this seems very slow on larger datasets. It also doesn't seem to be the way that mutate normally works.

```r
library(tidyverse)

valid_string <- function(string) {
  # Check the length
  if (stringr::str_length(string) != 10) {
    return(FALSE)
  }
  return(TRUE)
}

# Create a tibble to test on
test_tib <- tibble::tibble(string = c("1504915593", "1504915594", "9999999999", "123"),
                           known_valid = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))

# Apply the function
test_tib <- dplyr::mutate(test_tib, check_valid = valid_string(string))
test_tib

valid_string2 <- function(string) {
  purrr::map_lgl(string, function(string) {
    # Check the length
    if (stringr::str_length(string) != 10) {
      return(FALSE)
    }
    return(TRUE)
  })
}

# Apply the function
test_tib <- dplyr::mutate(test_tib, check_valid2 = valid_string2(string))
test_tib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you rewrite your function as `vectorized` function like this:

```
valid_string <- function(string) {
  # Check the length
  ifelse(stringr::str_length(string) != 10, FALSE, TRUE)
}
```

Another option would be the `Vectorize` function from `base` which would work like this:

```
valid_string2 <- function(string) {
  # Check the length
  if(stringr::str_length(string) != 10) {
    return(FALSE)
  }
  return(TRUE)
}
valid_string2 <- Vectorize(valid_string2)
```

Both work pretty good, however I would suggest the solution with `ifelse`.

```
# Create a tibble to test on
test_tib <- tibble::tibble(string = c("1504915593", "1504915594", "9999999999", "123"),
                           known_valid = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))

# Apply the function
test_tib <- dplyr::mutate(test_tib, check_valid = valid_string(string))
test_tib <- dplyr::mutate(test_tib, check_valid2 = valid_string2(string))
test_tib


  string     known_valid check_valid check_valid2
  <chr>      <lgl>       <lgl>       <lgl>       
1 1504915593 TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        
2 1504915594 TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        
3 9999999999 TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        
4 123        FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, Vectorize seems to work, just running some tests to see if the speed is any different between using purr::map, sapply or Vectorize.
I don't think I can use ifelse or dplyr::if_else since my actual function is quite  abit more complicated than that provided.

Comment: ok great, let us know. If everything works as expected, accepting the answer would be nice :-)

Comment: Speeds seem to be comparable between the 3 methods but I think Vectorized is the cleanest and minimizes dependancies...
I managed to get a 20X speed up though profiling and microbenchmark... I probably should have done that in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
test_tib <- dplyr::mutate(test_tib, checkval = ifelse(nchar(string)!=10,FALSE,TRUE))
```

Comment: Nope, sorry, as I say in the question, the actual function is quite a bit more complicated that that provided above. But in essence it takes a string and returns a TRUE or FALSE.